# NestJS how get access in pipe to repository in abscract controller

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have BaseController ( Abstract )
that contains pipe CanGetPipe

```
export abstract class CanGetPipe implements PipeTransform {
  protected abstract readonly repository: Repository<IEntry>;
...
```

and mixin for it

```
export const makeCanGetPipe = (repoName: any) =>
  mixin(
    class extends CanGetPipe {
      protected readonly repository = getConnection().getRepository<IEntity>(repoName);
    },
  );
```

Get method of BaseControlle looks like:

```
  @Get('/:id')
  @UsePipes(makeCanGetPipe(REPOSITORY_NAME_FROM_CHILD_CONTROLLER))
  getOne(@ValidateData() validate: ValidateParam, @Param('id') id: number) {
    return this.Service.get(id, validate);
  }
```

How i can set `REPOSITORY_NAME_FROM_CHILD_CONTROLLER` in child Controller than inherited from BaseController?

Or, how i can have access to repository (service, dependency) of child Controller in pipe that assigned to BaseController?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to access something in child class that is found i the parent class? Like     super

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use combination of:

1. `@SetMetadata('repoName', YOUR_VALUE)` on your child class
2. Instead of Pipe - use Guard with `const repoName = this.reflector.get<string>('repoName', context.getClass());`

That should do the trick and you'll be able to get custom repo for your BaseGuard :)